# Export/Download D3 tree (SVG) to PNG/PDF

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert D3 Collapsible Tree (SVG) into PNG or PDF Format. I've an example code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PJAY_DEVELOPER/pzwebheo/#&togetherjs=z6EsApClme) which I've developed using a worked [example](http://bl.ocks.org/Rokotyan/0556f8facbaf344507cdc45dc3622177).

```
function drawCanvas(){
         var svgString = getSVGString(svg.node());
         svgString2Image( svgString, 960, 600, 'png', save ); // passes Blob and filesize String to the callback

     function save( dataBlob, filesize ){
              saveAs( dataBlob, 'Test.png' ); // FileSaver.js function
     }

}

// Set-up the export button
d3.select('#saveButton').on('click', function(){
    var svgString = getSVGString(svg.node());
    console.log(svgString);
    svgString2Image( svgString, 2*width, 2*height, 'png', save ); // passes Blob and filesize String to the callback
function save( dataBlob, filesize ){
    saveAs( dataBlob, 'D3 vis e
```

I think there may be an issue with node style or library. Can anyone help and explain why this is not printing?

Comment: You should include your code in the question

Comment: @ David Lee the code I've put is in JSFiddle, the link is in example. Cheers